# React unit test with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: c#, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

My Component.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class CheckboxWithLabel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isChecked: false};
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange() {
    this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.state.isChecked}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        {this.state.isChecked ? this.props.labelOn : this.props.labelOff}
      </label>
    );
  }
}
```

UnitTest:

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, {shallow, mount, render} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import CheckboxWithLabel from './CheckboxWithLabel';

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

test('CheckboxWithLabel changes the text after click', () => {
  // Render a checkbox with label in the document
  const checkbox = render(<CheckboxWithLabel labelOn="On" labelOff="Off" />);
  expect(checkbox.text()).toEqual('Off');
  checkbox.find('input').simulate('change');
  expect(checkbox.text()).toEqual('On');
});
```

when I use shallow and mount, my unit test gets passed but when I'm using render it's getting failed.
Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: 4 of 5 tags here are wrong

Comment: tags are attached not only w.r.t content but also number of persons followed by it